# Terminating a particular thread on specific condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a program, where there are multiple threads running in an infinite loop. Each thread can handling a certain number of tasks say MAXTASKFOREACHTHREAD. A new thread is generated when the number of tasks increases. If MAXTASKFOREACHTHREAD is not reached, new task will be added into it. But if the task is completed such that number of task in a thread = 0, at a particular point. I want to terminate that thread. I don't want that thread to keep waiting for a task. A new thread can be spawned as needed.

```
class ThreadPool
{
   void createThread();
   static void threadFunc(ThreadPool *);
   private:
   thread t;
   int val = 0;
}
void ThreadPool::createThread()
{
  t = thread(threadFunc, this);
}

void ThreadPool::threadFunc();
//carries the function implementation regarding tasks

int main()
{
  vector<ThreadPool *> v;
  v.push_back(new ThreadPool());
  v.push_back(new ThreadPool());
  v.push_back(new ThreadPool());
  v[0].createThread();
  v[1].createThread();
  v[2].createThread();
  
}

// Code might have syntax error, I just typed out!
// Now how should I proceed with the deletion of thread, without causing memory corruption!, I need to delete the corresponing object, of the thread
// I am looking for a idea, how to deal with this, without increasing the complexity by using locks.
```

Please give some suggestions!
If any part is not clear that add in comments.

Comment: return from the function is running?

Comment: IMO best solution is to use `std::async` instead `std::thread` and let standard library decide how many threads are running.

Comment: What is actually your question? The approach you have chosen will work but be aware there is non-trivial overhead in creating a new thread so perhaps you could recycle them?

Comment: A thread ends when the function which defines it terminate: so just exit the function when the task number is 0

Comment: How will I know which thread has 0 task? One is to keep its track from main thread. Which will increase complexity, i don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're forgetting that threads run code. You can simply use the worker thread itself to check if there's more work.

First, let's clear up some confusion. A ThreadPool holds multiple threads. In your case, `v` would be that pool. `std::vector` is not really a convenient interface for that. So, rename your existing `ThreadPool` to `WorkerThread`, and create a `ThreadPool` with a `private: std::vector<WorkerThread>`. (objects, not pointers)

The `WorkerThread` cooperates with `ThreadPool`. Your `WorkerThread::threadFunc` has a main loop that checks if there is work. If so, it's executed. But if there's no work, that's the case where you retire the thread. You exit the thread main loop, tell the `ThreadPool` you're done, and let it call `join`. Alternatively, `detach` the WorkerThreads.

Another way to remove threads is to make a special task in the ThreadPool, which causes the WorkerThread which picks it up to exit its main loop. This could be implemented as an empty `std::function<>`, for instance. In this way, you can actively reduce the number of threads, even if there is work left.

Comment: Thanks, this will work. But I am also curious about my current state. Suppose v[1] tasks finishes, now how do I free thread. As object is already created and saved in the vector. I think in this case we might not remove it!

Comment: @zenitsu: Just because your thread is in a a vector doesn't really change things. You `.join` the thread, and then call `delete` on it. Of course calling `delete` on a `thread*` is somewhat missing the point - `thread` itself is already a handle-like type.  And since you put these things in a `vector` you have to deal with the problem of eraing a member in the middle, but that too is your design choice.

Comment: Since my thread is running in an infinite loop, waiting for tasks. If I call join on it from main thread, will it not block my main thread? I dont want to block my main thread, as I intend to busy my main thread with other executions. Is there any way?

Comment: @zenitsu: You would of course only `join` threads that you known have exited their main loop, or are about to do so. That's why I suggested that `WorkerThreads` tell the `ThreadPool` when they're finished.